# Where can I find documentation on Google's search options that show up in the url address?

Tags: google-search

By adding certain code terms to a Google search, one can control certain options about the result.

For instance, "encrypted.google.com/search?&hl=en&q=TEST" searches for "TEST" in the English language sites.  Here the code used is "hl=en".

Similarly, "&num=100" results in 100 results per page.

Where can I find documentation on ALL of these "search codes"?